# Does anyone know how to get Linux to recognize my Pinnacle video digitizer box?

Tags: video

I have a Pinnacle Video Studio capture box and was wondering if anyone out there had gotten Linux to work with it or any of its brethren (Dazzle, Ultimate studio, etc.)? It connects through the USB port and then to any composite/S-video source. There is no tuner, just video.

Answer (score 1):

Much can depend on the chip. This works for the EasyCap DC60+ which is based on an Empia 2861 chip.

With it plugged in type lsusb in a terminal to find out what type it is if the following doesn't work.

Assuming it is supported, using VLC it should be easy. Connect the device and open VLC. In VLC select media/open capture device. If using S video as a source, hit play. If using composite you will need to take an additional step - hit advanced options and then in the video input box select 1 (that's composite - s video is 0 (default).

If all is good on the video front, there is then audio. If it works - great. If it doesn't,like on the Easycap you can always bypass the card with a 2XRCA into 3.5 jack and plug it into the mic/line in socket.
Hope this helps.